# What IDE can I use to open the MoveIt repository as a whole project?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm curious as to what IDEs are in use within the community who are working on MoveIt, and if there are any project definitions already in existence that would enable me to open the MoveIt code in a meaningful and organised manner?

I know CMake can generate projects for various IDEs and Make systems, but I haven't had much luck with this option thus far. If this is a viable approach, a succinct tutorial showing how to do this would be just fine.

For C++ work, I use Xcode on MacOS and Code::Blocks on linux, but I do have Eclipse and Netbeans installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310957/what-ide-can-i-use-to-open-the-moveit-repository-as-a-whole-project?/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

You can open ROS packages with different IDEs, from my experience the best are KDevelop, Eclipse and QtCreator.
Follow the instructions on the wiki page stated above and you will be able to create a project that will correctly parse all the inclusions.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2018-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2018-12-20**:
@VictorLamoine:  I'm following the guide you linked with QtCreator 4.8 (based on Qt5.12.0).  Under the Catkin Tools section, there is a comment *Make sure, that the build folder is set to ws/build/your_package instead of ws/build*.  Could you please refresh me on where this setting is done?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-12-20**:
When you configure the project you are asked for different configurations, you can choose the build directory here. After configuring a project you can modify these settings in "Projects" on the left panel.